# How to render large list in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have one problem with flatlist
when i rendering many images (like gallery) in console i see this warnings

"VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {dt: 1393, prevDt: 582, contentLength: 5130}"

and even when I rengering empty view

and  my component extended PureComponent

Comment: Post your code, specially your render method.

Comment: `renderItem(data) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.openImage.bind(this,item,index)}
                style={styles.imageView}>
            <Image
                source={{uri:item.photo_130}}
                style={styles.image}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    )

}
`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `shouldItemUpdate` to determine if items should be updated.

Comment: shouldItemUpdate was deprecated